# Magento 2.4.5 Duplicate key name 'WISHLIST_CUSTOMER_ID'

Tags: magento2.4, magento-community, magento-commerce

I am facing strange issue on the Magento 2.4

I have upgraded my Magento store to the latest version, and after the upgrade, I am facing one strange issue while running upgrade command.

It's looks like Magento default issue.

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1061 Duplicate key name 'WISHLIST_CUSTOMER_ID', query was: ALTER TABLE `wishlist` ADD CONSTRAINT `WISHLIST_CUSTOMER_ID` UNIQUE KEY (`customer_id`)
```

[image]

Magento is going to add the foreign key in the wishlist table, but that key already exists, so as per the common logic, it should be skipped, but that is not happening and it's throwing error.

[image]

Apart from the above issue, I have found solution for it on stackexchange but that is not a correct way.

[setup:upgrade SQL error after update from 2.2.8 to 2.3.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/275628/setupupgrade-sql-error-after-update-from-2-2-8-to-2-3-1)

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove duplicate `customer_id` in `wishlist` table

List duplicate `customer_id`

```
SELECT 
    customer_id, 
    COUNT(customer_id)
FROM
    wishlist
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING COUNT(customer_id) > 1;
```

Remove them

```
DELETE FROM wishlist WHERE wishlist_id in (...);
```

Comment: My wishlist table is already empty so this is not an solution.